# SED deleting words with extension

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Lets say I have something like this

```
OBJ=GameBook main.cpp Game.cpp Game.h Storyline.cpp Storyline.h
```

How do I delete words which end on .h (header files) using SED ?

So far I have `sed 's/\<.*\.h\>//g'`
This deletes whole line, not the words I want.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
sed 's/[a-zA-Z]*.h *//g'
```

If you have `< ... >` surrounding the string then you could do:

```
sed 's/<*[a-zA-Z]*.h>* *//g'
```

**Result**:

```
OBJ=GameBook main.cpp Game.cpp Storyline.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

It works also with:

```
sed s/.\\w\\+.h//g text.txt
```

**Result:**

```
OBJ=GameBook main.cpp Game.cpp Storyline.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sed too

```
sed 's/^\| [^ ]*\.h//g'
```